# Query to get all the rows that have the same date with respect to their invoice numbers?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table from which I have to get invoiceNo, Sum of all the weights, count the number of barcodes and the last value in sum_total from table called selected_items for a particular date.

```
    SELECT invoiceNo, SUM(weight), COUNT(barcode), sum_total
FROM selected_items
WHERE date LIKE '07-Jan-2016' GROUP BY invoiceNo ORDER BY id DESC;
```

This is what my database looks like.
[image]

This what I get in output when I run this query in php my admin.
[image]

What I am wanting to do is get the invoiceNo, sum of weight,count of barcodes and the last value in sum_total for that particular invoiceNo on a certain date.
In my current query I am getting the sum of weight for 6 items,barcode count as 6 and the first value in sum_total. I have even tried this query but it does not give the expected answer.

```
SELECT invoiceNo, SUM(weight), COUNT(barcode), sum_total
FROM selected_items
WHERE invoiceNo IN ('IN1001','ES102');
```

This is what I am expecting to achieve.[image]

Comment: the last value in sum_tota so Order by id DESC?

Comment: Are you really storing dates as text? O.o

Comment: @Naruto I tried it but it did not work for me I am new to programming can you help!

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos yes I am finding it easier to use it as a string in my java code

Comment: Aggregate functions but no `GROUP BY`?!?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "last" value on a particular date, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: Store dates using a date data type. Then get back to us.

Comment: Using dates as text makes you loose all date related function benefits from your database. I'd advise you to not do it like this. If you are using Java 8, you can use the new [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) API. Java 7 is a bit trickier, you'd have to use the old [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) API, but it's not that complicated.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos we are just about to submit this project in college I will definitely work on your suggestions once I am done with my exam.Thanks :)

Comment: @jarlh thanks for the edit :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff MySQL really mess up with newbie heads. Other DBMSs would not allow this kind of things because it does not make sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried using this query SELECT invoiceNo, SUM(weight), COUNT(barcode), sum_total
FROM selected_items
WHERE date LIKE '07-Jan-2016' ORDER BY sum_total DESC LIMIT 1 GROUP BY invoiceNo; but I get an error  check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY invoiceNo' at line 3.

Comment: I'm really confused about your data. The `sum_total` seems like a sum of all existing records with the same `invoicNo`. Is this correct?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos the last value in sum_total is the sum of all the items selected.So I want to access the last value in sum_total for that particular invoiceNo.

Comment: And the before-last value? In "ES101" the `sum_total` seems to be 2 times the value of the first one, while the last value seems to be 3 times the value of the first. Is that correct?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos yes that's correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100047/discussion-between-androidnewbee-and-henrique-barcelos).

Comment: Sorry, cant' chat. Work network is blocked for chats. Just for the record: your data modeling does not makes much sense to me.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos I know but right now I have no option. I had a similar problem before I had used this query Select * From (SELECT t.*, a_rownum := a_rownum + 1 AS rank FROM selected_items t, (SELECT a_rownum := 0) r order by rank DESC) si GROUP BY si.invoiceNo; and my problem was solved.Here at the rate is a_.

Answer (score 4):

To achieve what you need, you should group your result by `invoiceNo`, so your query looks like this:

```
SELECT invoiceNo, SUM(weight), COUNT(barcode), sum_total
FROM selected_items
WHERE date LIKE '07-Jan-2016' GROUP BY invoiceNo;
```

Comment: Thanks man this works but the only problem is i also want the last value in sum_total for a particular invoiceNo :)

Comment: @AndroidNewBee then SUM(sum_total) ?

Comment: @BobNocraz the last value in sum_total is the final sum can you help me access that

Comment: @AndroidNewBee try MAX(sum_total)  looking at your posted image, this may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Several things i'd like to say. It seems your data has no primary index, which is very bad for search speed, so i'd recommend you add some `id` field with `autoincrement` property, and then add `ORDER BY id DESC` to get latest result.

Comment: @BobNocraz i tried MAX(sum_total) it din work it still gave me the same result.

Comment: @Eternal1 i have made the changes you suggested I have also updated my question.It still does not give the desired output can you please take a look.Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This might help you do give it a try.

```
SELECT invoiceNo, SUM( weight ) , COUNT( barcode ) , sum_total
FROM (SELECT * FROM  `selected_items` 
WHERE DATE LIKE  '07-Jan-2016'
ORDER BY id DESC
)a
GROUP BY invoiceNo;
```